# Select especific nodes in XML (Loop)

Tags: php, xml

I can't access only one node of an xml

```
<destinos>
 <destino>
     <programas>
       <item>
        <location>Spain</location>
        ...more content
       </item>
       <item>
        <location>USA</location>
       ...more content
       </item>
     </programas>
 </destino>
 <destino>
     <programas>
       <item>
        <location>France</location>
        ...more content
       </item>
       <item>
        <location>Brasil</location>
       ...more content
       </item>
     </programas>
 </destino>
</destinos>
```

I need:

```
<item>
  <location>Spain</location>
  ...more content
</item>
<item>
  <location>USA</location>
  ...more content
</item>
<item>
  <location>France</location>
  ...more content
</item>
<item>
  <location>Brasil</location>
  ...more content
</item>
```

i tried:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml');

foreach ($xml->destinos->destino->programas as $resultado){
    echo $resultado->asXML();
}

or

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);


$items = $xml->xpath("//destino/programas");

header('Content-Type: application/xml');

foreach ($items as $personaje) {
   echo $personaje->asXML();
}
```

But I only get the first two "item" of "program" or four elements but error in xml in the second example.

Thanks for the help, I have looked for solutions but I have not been able to find any that will help me solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried looping over `$xml->destinos->destino` first?

Comment: Yes, but I can't get all the "item".

Comment: What does that mean? Can you share all approaches you've tried?

Comment: I tried: 

$nodes = $xml->xpath("/destinos/destino/programas/item");

header('Content-Type: application/xml');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
 
    echo $node->asXML();
   
}

Comment: Please add all approaches to the question. And have you tried to loop over `/destinos/destino` first? This might help to pick up all `program` nodes instead of only the nodes from the very first `program`

Comment: My knowledge is not very good in PHP, I'm sorry. I'm trying.

Comment: All the items MUST be under a root element to be valid XML.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes! That is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a fudge as it 'manually' adds in a root element.  The main loop uses XPath to find all of the `<item>` tags and then just outputs the content.

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml');

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

echo "<root>";
foreach ($xml->xpath("//item") as $item){
    echo $item->asXML();
}
echo "</root>";
```